# Which methods gets called when the user presses the standby button?

Tags: android, android-activity

Other than onPause() are there any callbacks that run when the user presses the standby/sleep button?
Like [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) when pressing the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF broadcast, but that's also sent when the screen timeouts by itself.